# Angular 2 application using webpack

Tags: angular, webpack-2

Earilier I had developed a sample Angular 2 application using System JS for module loading , and it was working fine.

Now I would like to use webpack module bundler instead of system JS, and I have made changes accordingly.

Now when I run application in browser , it displayes below error in the console.

> "Cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomeComponent'
>   Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomeComponent'"

Below is my root module code related to routing

```
RouterModule.forRoot( [
              {path:'' , component:HomeComponent},
              {path:'acategories/:id/products/:pid' , component:ProductComponent},
              //{path:'acategories/productsx/:pid' , component:ProductComponent},
              {path:'acategories/:id/products' , component:ProductsComponent},                  
              {path:'acart' , component:CartComponent},
              {path:'about' , component:AboutComponent},
              {path:'aorders' , component:OrderDetailsComponent},
              {path:'asearch' , component: ProductSearchComponent},
              {path:'**',component:PageNotFoundComponent}
          ]),
```

Below is my root component code

```
@Component({    
    selector:'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'

})
```

app.component.html has

```
 ...
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 ...
```

and this is my Home component code

```
@Component({ 
selector:'',
templateUrl:'./home.component.html'
})
```

All these files are in the same folder.
Any idea what needs to be modified.

Comment: which is your bootstraped component ?

Comment: bootstrap:[AppComponent]

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep the selector of home component empty and try to use it somewhere in the Html.

Comment: what does it mean ? what the benefit for doing this ? may be you are right but i does't relate to problem i think

Answer (score 0):

It was templateUrl path issue in my components , had to modify

```
@Component({    
selector:'my-app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html'

})
```

to

```
@Component({    
selector:'my-app',
templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'

})
```

After using fiddler to check what was returned from server , was able to identify the issue.